# Running tests that require vulkan-1.dll during pipline build

Tags: azure-pipelines, vulkan

I'm trying to get a simple ctest scenario working with vulkan on azure-pipelines `windows-2019` vmimage.

As far as I'm aware the CPUs in the free-tier should support vulkan as they are broadwell or skylake based.

However when my tests are run i recieve a crash report with the following error `Exit code 0xc0000135` which means there is a missing DLL.

I'm making an assumption that it is a vulkan-1.dll driver that is missing because everything else that is built is pushed into the same directory.

The build works fine with the vulkan SDK on the pipeline, just the test .exe fails to run. The test .exe run completely fine locally. I'm also assuming that the SDK installation would install the vulkan-1.dll driver too, but I'm not sure.

Is there a way to verify that azure is looking for the vulkan dll and not finding it? How can I verify that the driver is installed on azure?

Comment: `vulkan-1.dll` is not installed by the SDK (anymore). It is installed by the GPU ICD. You can install it though: there's "Latest Runtime" at https://vulkan.lunarg.com/sdk/home, which installs the dll. Though that does not imply you have a Vulkan capable driver; it is just the Loader.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@krOoze 's Solution works on azure. All I needed to do was download the "Latest Runtime" and place the vulkan-1.dll in the directory with the test .exe

Tests now run on azure!

Comment: Can you please share the part of your `azure-pipeline.yml` that does the installation?